# Can you set a SharePoint site Locale and Languages using Powershell PnP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am working on a Powershell script to create new SharePoint sites using the [Pattern and Practices libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps). I need to change the **locale** and add an **alternative language** to "Classic Team" sites.

Is this possible with the PnP library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `get-pnpcontext` cmdlet. So to add e.g. German (LCID 1031) to your sharepoint site you can use:

```
$Context = Get-PnPContext
$Web = $Context.Web
$Context.Load($Web)
Invoke-PnPQuery

$Web.IsMultilingual = $true
$Web.AddSupportedUILanguage(1031)
$Web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!